# Validate angular input form from javascript ( chrome console)

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

Our company develop a new intranet platform in angular.

I try to automatize some task from chrome console, but I can't "dirty" (validate fields for submit) angular form for submit automatic from javascript.

I Can give a text value, but can't submit because angular detect field invalid while I don't physycaly press a key on input

I tried to:

- Get a value to input from jquery
- Keydown, Keypress, Keyup, focus and blur event

But I don't found a way.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you call

`formName.markAsDirty()`?

That should work if you can access it.

Comment: it doesn't work, function doesn't found.

It should be possible lie to angular which may believe that I input physycally from keyboard